# Speeding up reading from InputStream and writing with FileOutputStream

Tags: java, performance, java-io

I'm reading some blob's from a column of a databse and them saving to a file using `FileOutputStream`.

This is my code:

```
InputStream binaryFile = rs_ivol.getBinaryStream("BLOB_COLUMN_FROM_BY_DB");
FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream(myoutpath);  
int aux = 0;
while ((aux = binaryFile.read()) != -1)
{
    outputFile.write(aux);
}
```

The thing is that this is extremelly slow. I need to convert more than 58225 items and it can take up to 24h.

Can someone tell me how can I make that *read-from-InputStream* → *write-to-FileOutputStream* somehow faster?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read and write using a buffer.

```
InputStream binaryFile = rs_ivol.getBinaryStream("BLOB_COLUMN_FROM_BY_DB");
FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream(myoutpath);  
int aux = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((aux = binaryFile.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    outputFile.write(buffer, 0, aux);
}
```

EDIT: 
See DwB's answer for an alternative to rolling your own buffer...

EDIT:
Also @Nicolas Filotto has a better suggestion too...

Comment: Thanks, now is *a bit* faster. If I increase that buffer, it would be even faster?

Comment: @Avion: Not much. The Performance bottleneck will probably the connection to the DB, i.e. reading the BLOB from the DB.

Comment: don't forget to close the streams

Comment: Wow, tester on a windows machine and the difference it's not very big, but I tested it on a linux machine and it's like 10000000 faster.

Comment: The size of the buffer will be best determined through trial and error to be honest.  In my experience, much more than 1 MiB (1024*1024) and you stop getting benefits, but experimentation is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have **Java 7 or higher** and you don't want to reinvent the wheel, consider using [`Files.copy(InputStream in, Path target, CopyOption... options)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) as next:

```
try (InputStream binaryFile = rs_ivol.getBinaryStream("BLOB_COLUMN_FROM_BY_DB")) {
    Files.copy(binaryFile, Paths.get(myoutpath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```